# Show that a limit is equal to 3/5 using just the definition of the limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to show that:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{3+7x}{5+5x} = \dfrac 35$$

I can not use algebra of limits.

In the answer it starts with $|x-0|=|x|<1/5 $.

Can anyone explains where this comes from?

It then uses inverse triangle equality to get
$|5+5x|\geq||5|-|5x||\geq 5-5|x|>5-1 = 4$.

I understand it uses the part above in this inequality but still cant see where it comes from.

The rest I can follow easily doing $|f(x)-L|$ etc.

Thanks

Comment: Use $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}f(x)}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}g(x)}$ where $f(x)=3+7x$ and $g(x)=5+5x$.

Comment: surely this is using algebra of limits?

Comment: Of course. And that can be proved from the definition.

Comment: the question given asks you to complete it without using algebra of limits :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $\frac{1}{5}$ chosen here is somewhat arbitrary. We could have been chosen any number in $(0,1)$.

The goal is to get a **lower** bound on $|5x+5|$ to get an **upper** bound for $\frac{1}{|5x+5|}$.  In this case, $\frac{1}{5}$ was chosen just to make the lower bound an integer.

Assume we had picked some $c\in(0,1)$ and assumed $|x|<c$. Then $|5x+5|\geq 5(1-c)$, so $\frac{1}{5+5x}\leq \frac{1}{5(1-c)}$ and $$\left |\frac{3+7x}{5+5x}-\frac{3}{5}\right|=\left|\frac{20x}{5(5+5x)}\right|\leq \left|\frac{20x}{25(1-c)}\right|$$

If we chose $c=\frac{1}{5}$, this just makes $\frac{20x}{25(1-c)}=x$, which is "nice," but not necessary. Given $\epsilon>0$ you can choose:

$$\delta = \min\left(c, \frac{4(1-c)\epsilon}{5}\right)$$

Comment: ah thank you! i didnt pick up on it could be any value, i thought there was a formula or something i had missed to derive it!